# What does the practical CPL skill test contain?

Tags: easa-regulations

In [EASA Part-FCL, FCL.310 containts](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Part-FCL.pdf) on several hundred pages all the required knowledge for the theoretical skill test for a CPL. However, different from other licenses described in Part-FCL (PPL, Aerobatic, VFR Night, Mountain, ...), there is no list of what's in the practical skill test.

What's included in the CPL practical skill test? What are the tolerances for maneuvers etc?

Comment: The section of the document on the CPL skills test says that the test requirements are in Appendix 4. Is the information in Appendix 4 what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Part-FCL.pdf

> Appendix 4 - Skill test for the issue of a CPL
>
> A. General
>   1. An applicant for a skill test for the CPL shall have received instruction on the same class or type of aircraft to be used in the
>   test.
>   2. An applicant shall pass all the relevant sections of the skill test. If any item in a section is failed, that section is failed.
>   Failure in more than one section will require the applicant to take
>   the entire test again. An applicant failing only in one section shall
>   only repeat the failed section. Failure in any section of the retest,
>   including those sections that have been passed on a previous attempt,
>   will require the applicant to take the entire test again. All relevant
>   sections of the skill test shall be completed within 6 months. Failure
>   to achieve a pass in all relevant sections of the test in two attempts
>   will require further training.
>   3. Further training may be required following any failed skill test. There is no limit to the number of skill tests that may be attempted.
>
> CONDUCT OF THE TEST
>   4. Should the applicant choose to terminate a skill test for reasons considered inadequate by the Flight Examiner (FE), the applicant shall
>   retake the entire skill test. If the test is terminated for reasons
>   considered adequate by the FE, only those sections not completed shall
>   be tested in a further flight.
>   5. At the discretion of the FE, any manoeuvre or procedure of the test may be repeated once by the applicant. The FE may stop the test at any
>   stage if it is considered that the applicant’s demonstration of flying
>   skills requires a complete re-test.
>   6. An applicant shall be required to fly the aircraft from a position where the PIC functions can be performed and to carry out the test as
>   if no other crew member is present. Responsibility for the flight
>   shall be allocated in accordance with national regulations.
>   7. An applicant shall indicate to the FE the checks and duties carried out, including the identification of radio facilities. Checks shall be
>   completed in accordance with the checklist for the aircraft on which
>   the test is being taken. During pre-flight preparation for the test,
>   the applicant is required to determine power settings and speeds.
>   Performance data for take-off, approach and landing shall be
>   calculated by the applicant in compliance with the operations manual
>   or flight manual for the aircraft used.
>   8. The FE shall take no part in the operation of the aircraft except where intervention is necessary in the interests of safety or to avoid
>   unacceptable delay to other traffic. B. Content of the skill test for
>   the issue of a CPL — Aeroplanes
>
> 1. The aeroplane used for the skill test shall meet the requirements for training aeroplanes, and shall be certificated for the carriage of
>      at least four persons, have a variable pitch propeller and retractable
>      landing gear.
> 2. The route to be flown shall be chosen by the FE and the destination shall be a controlled aerodrome. The applicant shall be responsible
>      for the flight planning and shall ensure that all equipment and
>      documentation for the execution of the flight are on board. The
>      duration of the flight shall be at least 90 minutes.
> 3. The applicant shall demonstrate the ability to: (a) operate the aeroplane within its limitations, (b) complete all manoeuvres with
>      smoothness and accuracy, (c) exercise good judgement and airmanship;
>      (d) apply aeronautical knowledge; and (e) maintain control of the
>      aeroplane at all times in such a manner that the successful outcome of
>      a procedure or manoeuvre is never seriously in doubt.
>
> FLIGHT TEST TOLERANCES
>   4. The following limits shall apply, corrected to make allowance for turbulent conditions and the handling qualities and performance of the
>   aeroplane used. Height normal flight ±100 feet with simulated engine
>   failure ±150 feet Tracking on radio aids ±5° Heading normal flight
>   ±10° with simulated engine failure ±15° Speed take-off and approach ±5
>   knots all other flight regimes ±10 knots
>
> CONTENT OF THE TEST
>   5. Items in section 2 (c) and (e)(iv), and the whole of sections 5 and 6 may be performed in an FNPT II or an FFS. Use of the aeroplane
>   checklists, airmanship, control of the aeroplane by external visual
>   reference, anti-icing/de-icing procedures and principles of threat and
>   error management apply in all sections.
>
> SECTION 1 — PRE-FLIGHT OPERATIONS AND DEPARTURE a Pre-flight,
>   including: Flight planning, Documentation, Mass and balance
>   determination, Weather brief, NOTAMS b Aeroplane inspection and
>   servicing c Taxiing and take-off Part-FCL – Appendices, AMC and GM V1,
>   June 2016 Go back to Appendices Go back to the content 1168 | P a g e
>   d Performance considerations and trim e Aerodrome and traffic pattern
>   operations f Departure procedure, altimeter setting, collision
>   avoidance (lookout) g ATC liaison – compliance, R/T procedures
>
> SECTION 2 GENERAL AIRWORK a Control of the aeroplane by external
>   visual reference, including straight and level, climb, descent,
>   lookout b Flight at critically low airspeeds including recognition of
>   and recovery from incipient and full stalls c Turns, including turns
>   in landing configuration. Steep turns 45° d Flight at critically high
>   airspeeds, including recognition of and recovery from spiral dives
>   eFlight by reference solely to instruments, including: (i) level
>   flight, cruise configuration, control of heading, altitude and
>   airspeed (ii) climbing and descending turns with 10°–30° bank (iii)
>   recoveries from unusual attitudes (iv) limited panel instruments f ATC
>   liaison – compliance, R/T procedures
>
> SECTION 3 — EN-ROUTE PROCEDURES a Control of aeroplane by external
>   visual reference, including cruise configuration Range/Endurance
>   considerations b Orientation, map reading c Altitude, speed, heading
>   control, lookout d Altimeter setting. ATC liaison – compliance, R/T
>   procedures eMonitoring of flight progress, flight log, fuel usage,
>   assessment of track error and re-establishment of correct tracking f
>   Observation of weather conditions, assessment of trends, diversion
>   planning g Tracking, positioning (NDB or VOR), identification of
>   facilities (instrument flight). Implementation of diversion plan to
>   alternate aerodrome (visual flight)
>
> SECTION 4 — APPROACH AND LANDING PROCEDURES a Arrival procedures,
>   altimeter setting, checks, lookout b ATC liaison - compliance, R/T
>   procedures c Go-around action from low height d Normal landing,
>   crosswind landing (if suitable conditions) e Short field landing f
>   Approach and landing with idle power (single-engine only) g Landing
>   without use of flaps h Post flight actions
>
> SECTION 5 — ABNORMAL AND EMERGENCY PROCEDURES This section may be
>   combined with sections 1 through 4 a Simulated engine failure after
>   take-off (at a safe altitude), fire drill b Equipment malfunctions
>   including alternative landing gear extension, electrical and brake
>   failure c Forced landing (simulated) d ATC liaison - compliance, R/T
>   procedures e Oral questions
>
> SECTION 6 — SIMULATED ASYMMETRIC FLIGHT AND RELEVANT CLASS OR TYPE
>   ITEMS This section may be combined with sections 1 through 5 a
>   Simulated engine failure during take-off (at a safe altitude unless
>   carried out in an FFS) b Asymmetric approach and go-around c
>   Asymmetric approach and full stop landing d Engine shutdown and
>   restart e ATC liaison – compliance, R/T procedures, Airmanship f As
>   determined by the FE — any relevant items of the class or type rating
>   skill test to include, if applicable: (i) aeroplane systems including
>   handling of autopilot (ii) operation of pressurisation system (iii)
>   use of de-icing and anti-icing system g Oral questions

Comment: Please use block-quotes if you are quoting a body of text that you did not write/author. You should also link to the original source document and cite the page/section/etc where you found the information, otherwise this is just a copy/paste answer with no attribution.

Comment: Got it.      Thanks.